# excel VBA wont work for large column numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I am sadly not very proficient in dealing with VBA coding, and this if a sample code i found online. The issue I have with this is that the code doesnt seem to like very large column numbers. when "LookupRange As Range" becomes A1:A10000 the VBA no longer works properly. For example the code

```
=singlecellextract(J1,D1:E5,2)
```

works perfectly but

```
=singlecellextract(J1,D1:E12000,2)
```

returns a #VALUE! error

Here is the VBA code i used for the function

```
Function SingleCellExtract(Lookupvalue As String, LookupRange As Range, ColumnNumber As Integer)
  Dim i As Long
  Dim result As String

  For i = 1 To LookupRange.Columns(1).Cells.Count
        If LookupRange.Cells(i, 1) = Lookupvalue Then
             result = result & " " & LookupRange.Cells(i, ColumnNumber) & ","
       End If
  Next i

       SingleCellExtract = Left(result, Len(result) - 1)
  End Function
```

Is there any chance for this code to work with large amount of column nubmers or better yet work with inputs such as A:A? many thanks.

edit: i changed the double to long but it doesnt seem to effect tthe outcome

Comment: You need to declare i as long, not double. Also when dealing with such a big amount of data you should work with bulk operations i.e. with ranges rather than individual cells.

Comment: If the range is fixed, I would prefix the range values with the dollar symbol to mark them as being absolute:  =singlecellextract($J1,$D$1:$E$12000,2)  or alternatively, set the Range as a defined Range in the spreadsheet.

Comment: It looks like an 'Index Match' could work for you, rather than VBA.  Try =INDEX($D$1:$D$12000, MATCH($J1,$E$1:$E$12000,0))

Comment: I am trying to return multiple matched values into a single cell, also I tried changing double to Longbut doesnt seem to fix the problem. Thanks

Comment: Your code works for me, albeit rather slowly.

Comment: It's more likely you have an error value somewhere in your data. Using arrays would speed up your code if you're using big ranges.

Comment: Sorry Im not very good in coding in VBA, is there any chance you can give a sample code or point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula seems to work fine (although slow) as long as there are no errors.
The following adjustment will make it ignore errors.

```
Function SingleCellExtract(Lookupvalue As String, _
                            LookupRange As Range, _
                            ColumnNumber As Integer)
  Dim i As Long
  Dim result As String

  For i = 1 To LookupRange.Columns(1).Cells.Count
        If Not (IsError(LookupRange.Cells(i, 1)) Or _
            IsError(LookupRange.Cells(i, ColumnNumber))) Then
            If LookupRange.Cells(i, 1) = Lookupvalue Then
                 result = result & " " & LookupRange.Cells(i, ColumnNumber) & ","
            End If
        End If
  Next i

       SingleCellExtract = Left(result, Len(result) - 1)
End Function
```

Comment: thanks, for the response! what are the recommended method I should use to increase the speed?

Comment: With your method, you are asking the code to go to each individual cell and inspect one at a time. As was suggested, you could read the entire range you want to inspect into an array and then parce it. Each time you inspect/interact with the worksheet costs time and effort.